# Are there any markerless Augmented Reality frameworks available?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, marker

I am trying to create an android app that uses a custom image as the trigger for a 3d image overlay. Since I am not using the standard black and white markers for this, it would be classified as markerless. I was wondering if there was any existing framework or program that I can use to make/ integrate into my app. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any existing project for markerless augmented reality?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635313/are-there-any-existing-project-for-markerless-augmented-reality)

Comment: Yea same idea, but I wanted to make this one more general. And I also wanted to know if not black and white images were classified as markerless, even though they trigger without the gps/accelerometer for location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qualcomm has its open source Augmented reality framework. They have a pretty good documentation and also code samples to help you understand how to use it. I have personally used this, and works like a charm. More about it [here](https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/mobile-technologies/augmented-reality.)

Comment: Yea I tried Vuforia before, not a big fan, but thanks anyways.

Comment: @Nerd Just wondering, if this AR Framework is exclusive for Qualcomm Devices (platform)?

Comment: @Tabs: Nope. It is opensource.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a document about tracking configurations using the [metaio sdk](https://dev.metaio.com/sdk/tracking-configuration/optical-tracking-technologies/markerless/)

Sample codes can be found here in the [tutorial](https://dev.metaio.com/sdk/tutorials/tracking-samples/) (free download link to the sdk is on the left):

This tutorial helped me a bunch. Hope it helps you too.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try the [ARtoolkit for android](http://www.artoolworks.com/products/mobile/artoolkit-for-android/)?

It has a big [community](http://www.artoolworks.com/community/forum/).